# Sequential animations in android studio, loop

Tags: java, android, loops, animation

I am pretty new in android programing, and I am trying to make a simple game. I'd like to have 3 squares, and on start button I want to generate a few random numbers and to rotate one of the squares. I am doing that in the loop, because I number of random numbers is not fixed.

```
package com.example.smartpc.memorygame;

import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MemoryGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgRed;
    ImageView imgGreen;
    ImageView imgBlue;
    Button btnStart;

    ArrayList<Integer>array=new ArrayList<>();
    int brojac=3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_memory_game);

        imgRed=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgRed);
        imgGreen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgGreen);
        imgBlue=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBlue);
        btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        final RotateAnimation animation=new RotateAnimation(0f,360f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,
                                                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        animation.setDuration(1000);

        imgRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgRed.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });

        imgGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgGreen.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });

        imgBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgBlue.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i=0;i<brojac;i++) {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int number = rand.nextInt() % 3;
                    if (number == 1) {
                        imgRed.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                    else if (number == 2) {
                        imgGreen.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                    else {
                        imgBlue.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need to wait until one animation finishes,and then I need to start another loop iteration. Does anyone have idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Probably not ideal, but as you know that your `animation` will last one second `animation.setDuration(1000);` could you do a sleep at the end of each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I tried, but the system sleeps 3 seconds if I have 3 iterations, and then starts animations. It doesn't execute animation code then sleep, but sleep and after whole loop it starts animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On btnStart click create only random number and depending on that start animation

```
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.nextInt() % 3;
            if (number == 1) {
                imgRed.startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else if (number == 2) {
                imgGreen.startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else {
                imgBlue.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
    });
```

In setAnimationListener when animation end then again create random number and depending on that start animation

```
    final RotateAnimation animation=new RotateAnimation(0f,360f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.nextInt() % 3;
            if (number == 1) {
                imgRed.startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else if (number == 2) {
                imgGreen.startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else {
                imgBlue.startAnimation(animation);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
     });
```

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly to do in "Do here" part. I tried to have global counter i which I increment there, not in a loop, but still loop ends all 3 iterations (initialy brojac is 3), and then all animations starts, not one ny one. Anything else I can do?

Comment: at time you start 3 animation right?Suppose you start  imgRed.startAnimation(animation); 1st.After finish imgRed you have to start imgGreen correct?

Comment: Something like that, but which one is first depends on random number I got from Random number generator. And my problem is that I want to increment brojac (variable that says how many iterations loop has) and in some point it would be 12 for example. So I cannot use AnimationSet and its methods. But yes, I want to start one animation, then to generate next random number in loop, and then to start animation for other square (maybe the same if the number is same). But I don't want them at the same time, but one after one.

Comment: I got idea. Sorry for dumb question, but how to know that it will execute 3 times, or whatever I want. I have some ideas, but they don't seem good. And thanks a lot for this! It was really helpful.